# Async data processing on tkinter - multiple loops block

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, asynchronous, tkinter

I have a base window application using tkinter App class (class App(tk.Tk)).
Base of the code to trigger run have the following code:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
app = App(loop)
loop.run_forever()
```

The initiation part of the App has the following, which contains a loop create task to the updater function:

```
def __init__(self, loop, interval=0.05):
        super().__init__()
        self.loop = loop
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)
        self.update_task = loop.create_task(self.updater(interval))
```

The updater function:

```
async def updater(self, interval):
        while True:
            self.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(interval)
```

A button triggers to start a connection in another file which deals with websocket data receiving and processing. After multiple iterations trying out different ways I stuck with threading as seem to perform fastest.
UPDATE: removed threading as was not properly used, same result with just calling the function.

```
def start_connection():
    data_connection.main()
```

Then websocket gets opened, a loop is created to pull data from the buffer with all messages using below. Not sure if this best way, but this is what I stuck with as it didn't block the GUI.

```
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1000)
async def stream_loop():
      async with sem: 
         asyncio.ensure_future(stream_loop())
         await stream_process()
    
asyncio.ensure_future(stream_loop())
```

The problem I am having is that I want to run the stats summary calculation on interval and not with every message that comes in, using below it works, but **it seems to block the messages from getting received and added to data frame while summary stats are processing**:

```
 async def recalculate_loop():
        async def refresh():
            await recalculate_market_stats()
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await refresh()
        await refresh()
 asyncio.ensure_future(recalculate_loop())
```

**Is there a way to run these multiple processes asynchronously and parallel using multiple cores in CPU? Or it's already going as fast as it can in the back end and makes no difference?**

Comment: I think you have the most common mistake - `target=` needs function's name without `()` - so called `callback` - and later it will use `()` to run it in separated thread.

Comment: @furas - I removed the treading part of the code, just initiate connection by data_connection.main().